# I want write next line with Async WriteFileEx

Tags: c++, windows

i want to write file(text) with WriteFileEx.
but i don't know... how to offset the next line.

It is pointless adding the length of string. I want to write it on a new line, not after the written string. I'm so curious about how to get offset on the next line, 
not behind the written.

I'll ask for your advice.

ex) abcde, fghij <- i want write next line this string (fghij)

```
OVERLAPPED  ov { 0 };
LARGE_INTEGER   nLarge { 0 };
WriteFileEx(m_handle, str.c_str(), str.length(), &ov, nullptr);

nLarge.QuadPart += ???(How can I get the location of the next line?)
ov.Offset = nLarge.LowPart; 
ov.OffsetHigh = nLarge.HighPart;
```

Comment: Why is it pointless?  Why do you want to do this?  You'd be overwriting a part of the file you just wrote.  Maybe you just want `str.find("\n")`  Overlapped I/O to disk is really hard to get right with not much gains.... what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why is it pointless adding length of string?

Comment: It is pointless, machines today have far too much RAM to ever notice any benefit from this kind of code.  WriteFile/Ex writes to the file system cache, not the disk.  If the amount of data is too large (multiple gigabytes) then you'd consider a memory-mapped file first.